# How to set alias to a text file or python file and call it by their alias?

Tags: python, bash, unix

I'm trying to figure out how to set an alias to a certain file then call them. How to make it work? I've tried to search it, but none of them seems to work the way that I want it to.

So when I `ps aux | grep python` I get the following output:

```
root      4226  0.0  0.3  30452  8204 pts/0    T    Jun24   0:00 python
```

It displays like this, but when my supervisor uses that command it displays the alias after the command. Why is that happening when I am issuing the command?

Comment: he?  Show the entire thing.  What you type, what you get, what your supervisor types, what he gets.  If he sees the python process and the grep process, you need to `grep -v grep` the results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To set an alias you edit either your own bash settings (~/.bashrc) or the global setting /etc/bash.bashrc

To set an alias you can simply enter a line like this one:

```
alias grep='grep --color'
```

This works by replacing anything you enter in your bash with the alias assignment. So if i were to enter:

```
cat someFile | grep -n nope
```

bash would execute the command as if i had typed:

```
cat someFile | grep --color -n nope'
```

So if you want to get the same output as your co-worker you'll just have to ask for the alias line or the bashrc as a whole and extract the aliases you need.

Comment: fun fact: to see that command that's working behind an alias you can enter 'type <alias>' in your bash to get the respective line.